# $C_2 \times C_2$ and $C_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

With the cyclic group $C_n $, why can't we say $C_4$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$?

Is it because 2 and 2 are not coprime?

Are there any other types i should watch out for?

Comment: I think you'll learn a lot by writing out the the multiplication of each of these groups.

Comment: Can you find an element in $C_2\times C_2$ of order $4?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot say that they are isomorphic because they are not.

For example, they have different number of elements of order $2$.

Comment: Are there any other types like that? Because when i see stuff like $C_{27} $ being isomorphic to three C threes, it makes me automatically think it would work for C four.

Comment: $C_{27}$ is **not** isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3\times C_3$.

Comment: Looks like im more confused than i thought

Comment: @snowman In general $C_m \times C_n \cong C_{mn}$ iff $m, n$ are coprime, and this extends in the obvious way to products $C_{m_1} \times \cdots \times C_{m_k}$.

Answer (score 2):

Two groups $G$ and $G'$ are said to be isomorphic if there is a bijection $\phi: G \rightarrow G', g \mapsto g'$ which preserves the group operation in the sense that $\phi(gh) = \phi(g) \phi(h)$ for all $g, h \in G$. In other words, if $\phi$ takes $g$ to $g'$ and $h$ to $h'$, then $\phi$ must take $gh$ to $g'h'$.  In particular, it can be shown that $\phi$ must map the identity element of $G$ to the identity element of $G'$ and $\phi$ must map an element in $G$ of order $k$ to an element in $G'$ of the same order $k$.  But $C_4$ has an element of order 4, while $C_2 \times C_2$ doesn't.  Hence, these two groups are not isomorphic.